# Java Springboot JPA ManytoManymapping between three entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-mapping

i have 3 seperate entities in my project.   Process, Customer, Agent.  this project is a process management project. i have to establish relationship between these three entities. i want to use JPA mapping .Process has many to many bidirectional relationship with both customer and agent.  and similarly customer and agent both have bidirectional many to many relationship with process.  what kind of mapping should i use between them.  when a process is deleted, if a customer was associated with that process, the customer entity shouldnt be deleted since that customer might be associated with another process. similarly for process-agent relationship.  below are the three entities.       class Process {

```
private UUID id;

private String name;

private String description;

private String deepLinkId;

private StatusDto status;

private TaskDto task;

private Set<CustomerEntity> customers;

private Set<AgentEntity> agents;
```

}
public class Customer {

```
private UUID id;
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private int roleId = 1;
private String name;
private UUID notificationId;
private String mobile;
private String email;
private Boolean active;
private Date iat;
private CountryEntity country;
private Set<ProcessEntity> processes;
```

}
public class Agent {

```
private UUID id;
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private int role_id = 2;
private String name;
private String mobile;
private String email;
private String companyName;
private Boolean active;
private String username;
private String password;
private Date iat;
private CompanyEntity company;
private Set<ProcessEntity> processes;
```

}

any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide the owner first. In bidirectional many to many relation, you have to set one entity as an owner. In your case if you want to delete `Process` entity and corresponding `customer` entity, then you have to set `Process` entity as owner.

You have to write this to set your required entity as an owner:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "process",CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<CustomerEntity> customers;
    
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "process",CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<AgentEntity> agents;
    
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "customer",CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<ProcessEntity> agents;
```

Data will be stored like this :

```
process1 - >  custormer1   // stored as a new record in table
process1 - >  customer 2   // stored as a new record in table

customer1 ->  process 2     // stored as a new record in table
customer2 ->  process 2    // stored as a new record in table
```

If you delete process1 then only corresponding row will be deleted from the table and if customer1 is associated with another process then it is stored as a different record so it won't be deleted.

Comment: when a process is deleted, if a customer was associated with that process, the customer entity should not  be deleted since that customer might be associated with another process.

Comment: Every process will be stored in new row with many to many relation with customer so you can set last process as empty as latest process will be stored in new row.